# How can I update a subcollection in firestore without also updating the parent document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a small app with a firestore database. It consists of a collection "stores" containing a field "address" and a subcollection "users" also containing a field "address". Both address fields consist of city, street and zipCode.

I'm trying to update the address field in my users subcollection implemented in Vue. This is my attempt:

```
updateAddress(storeId, userId, address) {
   db.collection("stores").doc(storeId).collection("users").doc(userId).update(address).then(...)
}
```

This code above updates the correct user as expected. BUT it also updates the address object on the store document.

How can I update only the user document and not the store document? I suspect I could rename  one of these address fields but I think there has to be a better way to avoid this double update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The code you showed only update the `userId` document. It does not in any way touch the `storeId` document. Can you show how you determined that it modifies both documents?

Comment: When I execute the update function there is a realtime update in my firestore UI in the firebase console. There both address objects are updated with the same data at the same time. No other users than me are working with this database.

Answer (score 0):

The posted update code works just fine. The error was caused by me.

I accidentally introduced another function "updateAddress" on a different vuex module. Since in vuex actions are called via

```
this.$store.dispatch("updateaddress", address)
```

there was no error thrown. So each time I tried to update the user address both updateAddress functions were called and both documents were updated simultaneously.

Starting fresh on the next morning helps discovering your own mistakes ;)

Thanks anyway.